# Exact Memory Size of argv in C

Tags: c, argv

So my professor gave me (where `x` is a C executable):

```
$ ./x y z w
```

He said the memory size of `argv` in `int main(int argc, char **argv)` is 48 bytes, including itself.

Can someone help explain this to me?

Comment: added homework tag. Please clarify a bit the question

Comment: can someone explain the size in bytes of each letter ,x ,y ,z ,w ?

Comment: argv itself contains four arguments [the ./x counts] plus a null pointer at the end, so that's 5*P where P is the size of a pointer. The string data itself takes a minimum of 10 bytes - 4+2+2+2 [each string requires a null byte at the end].

That can't possibly result in 48. On a 32-bit system it would be 30, on a 64-bit system it would be 50.

Comment: The size of `argv` is equal to `sizeof(char**)`, which is typically equal to (and never bigger than) `sizeof(void*)`. I imagine you (or your professor) actually meant something else.

Answer (score 4):

`argv` is, as the function says, a pointer to a pointer to a char, which in terms of size means it's a pointer. Generally (almost always but not guaranteed?), all pointers are the same size. If this is a 64-bit machine, pointers will be 8 bytes in size. In this case, `argv` contains five elements: pointers to five char pointers: './x', 'y', 'z', 'w', and NULL, since `argv` is NULL-terminated.

By my calculations, that leaves 40 bytes in `argv`, so I'm not sure where he's getting the other 8.

**Edit:** As someone else suggested, `argv` itself would also take up room for a pointer, so there's the other 8.

Comment: +1 I think this is most likely what the professor meant; the memory overhead of `argv` itself, not the memory used to store the strings.

Answer (score 3):

There are four strings, requiring a total of 10 bytes (including the null terminators).
There are five pointers to strings (remember that `argv[4]` exists and is equal to `NULL`), each requiring 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform, so 40 bytes.
There is also `argv` itself, which is another 8 bytes.

So I count 58 bytes in total.  (This becomes 34 bytes on a 32-bit platform.)

Answer (score 3):

Technical answers aside, I think that your professor wants to help you understand *how* arguments are passed to your C program, and how variables are stored in memory. The size of the memory is really just used to illustrate the point.

The key things to understand are as follows:

1. Command-line arguments are passed to a C program as null-terminated strings
2. `argv[0]` contains the name and/or path of the program that is being executed
3. `argv[]` is a NULL-terminated array (`argv[argc]` is always NULL)
4. `argv` is an array of *pointers*
5. `argv` itself is also a pointer

Answer (score 2):

The size of argv is exactly `sizeof argv`. I doubt it is 48 in your teacher's computer.

```
argv : [ | | | | | | | ] pointer to values of type char*
       \-------V-------/
               > argv[0] : [ | | | | | | | ] pointer to char ==> [.|/|x|0]...
               > argv[1] : [ | | | | | | | ] pointer to char ==> [y|0]...
               > argv[2] : [ | | | | | | | ] pointer to char ==> [z|0]...
               > argv[3] : [ | | | | | | | ] pointer to char ==> [w|0]...
               > argv[4] : [0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0] NULL pointer

So, at least 8 + 5*8 + 10 >= 58 bytes

Or, if you prefer pointers 4-bytes long
at least 4 + 5*4 + 10 >= 34 bytes
```